# How to import data from Excel to C# Service based database?

Tags: c#, excel

Im using **C#** and **Service based** **database** and I need to import some data from  **Excel** to my database ..How could I possibly do this??  Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the excel file with the Excel database driver and read it like any other data source, however this means you need the driver, which isn't installed by default.

[Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

[HowTo](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306572/how-to-query-and-display-excel-data-by-using-asp-net-ado-net-and-visua)

However if the sheet only contains data and doesn't need any calculations, you can unzip the XLSX file, and find sheet1.xml (or whatever it's called in your file), open it in your app like any other XML file and import the data.

This is likely to be a much better long term solution, since MS has been trying to kill off the Access database driver for ages.

Also, it's been a while, but I don't believe MS recommends using the MSDE from within a service.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage` or `EPPlus` to read/write excel files. Bellow is some links to reference

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage/
- https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/import-and-export-data-using-epplus-core/
- https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2012/create-excel-20072010-spreadsheets-with-c-and-epplus/
- http://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-xlsx-asp-net-core/
- https://toidicodedao.com/2015/11/24/series-c-hay-ho-epplus-thu-vien-excel-ba-dao-phan-1/
- http://www.zachhunter.com/2015/11/xlsx-template-with-epplus-and-web-api-save-as-xlsx-or-pdf/